# Client socket - get IP - java

Tags: java, sockets, client

I am implementing a TCP connection with sockets and I need to get the IP of the client socket on the server side. I have used the `socketName.getRemoteSocketAddress()` which indeed returns the IP address followed by the port id I am using! how can I get just the address and not the port?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `SocketAddress` that this returns is actually a [protocol-dependent subclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketAddress.html). For internet protocols, such as TCP in your case, you can cast it to an [`InetSocketAddress`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html):

```
InetSocketAddress sockaddr = (InetSocketAddress)socketName.getRemoteSocketAddress();
```

Then you can use the methods of `InetSocketAddress` to get the information you need, e.g.:

```
InetAddress inaddr = sockaddr.getAddress();
```

Then, you can cast that to an [`Inet4Address`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html) or [`Inet6Address`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html) depending on the address type (if you don't know, use `instanceof` to find out), e.g. if you know it is IPv4:

```
Inet4Address in4addr = (Inet4Address)inaddr;
byte[] ip4bytes = in4addr.getAddress(); // returns byte[4]
String ip4string = in4addr.toString();
```

Or, a more robust example:

```
SocketAddress socketAddress = socketName.getRemoteSocketAddress();

if (socketAddress instanceof InetSocketAddress) {
    InetAddress inetAddress = ((InetSocketAddress)socketAddress).getAddress();
    if (inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address)
        System.out.println("IPv4: " + inetAddress);
    else if (inetAddress instanceof Inet6Address)
        System.out.println("IPv6: " + inetAddress);
    else
        System.err.println("Not an IP address.");
} else {
    System.err.println("Not an internet protocol socket.");
}
```

Comment: worked perfectly just by using your first tip (before edit). Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
((InetSocketAddress)socketName).getAddress().toString()
```

will return something like :`/10.255.34.132` that contains the host name, you could try this if you don't want the host name:

```
((InetSocketAddress)socketName).getAddress().toString().split("/")[1]
```